# Hyperledger Build error: Error creating new Smart Contract: Error chaincode id not provided

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am learning how to use Hyperledger Fabric DLT framework.

I am building an application that allows a seller of *Tuna* to transact with a buyer at a discount without compromising the marker price at which the seller sells to other buyers.

**Problem**: However each time a execute the code this message is thrown

`2018-01-14 18:45:11.292 EST [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 001 Chaincode log level not provided; defaulting to: INFO`

`2018-01-14 18:45:11.292 EST [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 002 Chaincode (build level: ) starting up ...`

**This is the error that I constantly get each time I run the code:**

`Error creating new Smart Contract: Error chaincode id not providedeloiim:fabric_`

This is the code I created

```
package main

import ( "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"; sc"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"; "bytes"; "encoding/json"; "strconv"; "fmt"; )

type SmartContract struct {
}

type Tuna struct {
  TxID int `json:"txid"`
  Container string `json:"container"`
  Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
  Location string `json:"location"`
  Owner string `json:"owner"`

}
```

**changeTunaHolder** - As the tuna fish is passed to different parties in the supply chain, the data in the world state can be updated with who has possession. The changeTunaHolder method takes in 2 arguments, tuna id and new holder name.

I suspect the error is with the changeTunaHolder method given that it takes the id and Owner fields

```
func (S_ *SmartContract) changeTunaHolder(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, parameters []string) sc.Response {

   if len(parameters) != 2 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2")
  }

  tunaAsBytes, _ := APIstub.GetState(parameters[0])
    if tunaAsBytes == nil {
        return shim.Error("Could not locate tuna")
    }

  TUNA := Tuna{}
  json.Unmarshal(tunaAsBytes, &TUNA)

  // Normally check that the specified argument is a valid holder of tuna
    // we are skipping this check for this example
    TUNA.Owner = parameters[1]

  tunaAsBytes, _ = json.Marshal(TUNA)

  _error := APIstub.PutState(parameters[0], tunaAsBytes)

  if _error != nil {
      return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to change tuna holder: %s", parameters[0]))
  }

  return shim.Success(nil)

 }
```

**Init METHOD** - In this the code attempts to retrieve the requested Smart Contract function and arguments

```
 func (S_ *SmartContract) Init(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
  return shim.Success(nil)
}

func (S_ *SmartContract ) Invoke(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {

    function, parameters := APIstub.GetFunctionAndParameters()

    if function == "queryTuna" {
      return S_.queryTuna(APIstub, parameters)

    } else if function == "initLedger"{
      return S_.initLedger(APIstub)

    } else if function == "recordTuna" {
      return S_.recordTuna(APIstub, parameters)

    } else if function == "changeTunaHolder"  {
      return S_.changeTunaHolder(APIstub, parameters)

    }
    return shim.Error("Invalid Smart Contract function name.")

   }
```

**queryTuna** - The queryTuna method would be used by a fisherman, regulator, or restaurateur to view the record of one particular tuna. It takes one argument - the key for the tuna in question.

```
func (S_ *SmartContract) queryTuna(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, parameters []string) sc.Response {

  if len(parameters) != 1{
    return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 1")
  }

  tunaAsBytes, _ := APIstub.GetState(parameters[0])

  if tunaAsBytes == nil {
    return shim.Error("Could not locate tuna")
  }
  return shim.Success(tunaAsBytes)

}
```

**initLedger** - The initLedger method will add test data to our network.

```
func (S_ *SmartContract) initLedger(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response{


  TUNA := []Tuna {

        Tuna{TxID: 1,Container: "923F", Location: "67.0006, -70.5476", Timestamp: "1504054225", Owner: "Miriam"},
        Tuna{TxID: 2,Container: "M83T", Location: "91.2395, -49.4594", Timestamp: "1504057825", Owner: "Dave"},
        Tuna{TxID: 3,Container: "T012", Location: "58.0148, 59.01391", Timestamp: "1493517025", Owner: "Igor"},
        Tuna{TxID: 4,Container: "P490", Location: "-45.0945, 0.7949", Timestamp: "1496105425", Owner: "Amalea"},
        Tuna{TxID: 5,Container: "S439", Location: "-107.6043, 19.5003", Timestamp: "1493512301", Owner: "Rafa"},
        Tuna{TxID: 6,Container: "J205", Location: "-155.2304, -15.8723", Timestamp: "1494117101", Owner: "Shen"},
        Tuna{TxID: 7,Container: "S22L", Location: "103.8842, 22.1277", Timestamp: "1496104301", Owner: "Leila"},
        Tuna{TxID: 8,Container: "EI89", Location: "-132.3207, -34.0983", Timestamp: "1485066691", Owner: "Yuan"},
        Tuna{TxID: 9,Container: "129R", Location: "153.0054, 12.6429", Timestamp: "1485153091", Owner: "Carlo"},
        Tuna{TxID: 10,Container: "49W4", Location: "51.9435, 8.2735", Timestamp: "1487745091", Owner: "Fatima"},
  }

  iter := 0

  for iter < len(TUNA) {
    println("iter is", iter)

    tunaAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(TUNA[iter])

    APIstub.PutState(strconv.Itoa(iter+1), tunaAsBytes)

    fmt.Println("ADDED", TUNA[iter])
    iter += 1
  }
  return shim.Success(nil)

}
```

**recordTuna** - The recordTuna method is the method a fisherman like Sarah would use to record each of her tuna catches. This method takes in five arguments (attributes to be saved in the ledger).

```
func (S_ *SmartContract) recordTuna(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, parameters[]string) sc.Response {
  if len(parameters) != 5 {
    return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 5")

  }
  TUNA  := Tuna{Container:parameters[1], Location:parameters[2], Timestamp:parameters[3], Owner:parameters[4]}

  tunaAsBytes, _:=json.Marshal(TUNA)
  _error := APIstub.PutState(parameters[0], tunaAsBytes)
  if _error != nil {
    return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to record tuna catch: %s", parameters[0]))
  }
  return shim.Success(nil)

}
```

**queryAllTuna** - The queryAllTuna method allows for assessing all the records; in this case, all the Tuna records added to the ledger. This method does not take any arguments. It will return a JSON string containing the results.

```
func (S_ *SmartContract) queryAllTuna(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {

  init_key := "0"
  end_key := "999"
  results_iterator, _error := APIstub.GetStateByRange(init_key, end_key)

  if _error != nil {
        return shim.Error(_error.Error())
  }
  defer results_iterator.Close()
  var buffer bytes.Buffer
  buffer.WriteString("[")

  b_array_member_already_written := false
  for results_iterator.HasNext() {
    query_response, _error := results_iterator.Next()
    if _error != nil {
            return shim.Error(_error.Error())
        }

    if b_array_member_already_written == true {
      buffer.WriteString(",")
    }
    buffer.WriteString("{\"Key\":")
        buffer.WriteString("\"")
        buffer.WriteString(query_response.Key)
        buffer.WriteString("\"")

    buffer.WriteString(", \"Record\":")

    buffer.WriteString(string(query_response.Value))
        buffer.WriteString("}")
    b_array_member_already_written = true
  }

  buffer.WriteString("]")
  fmt.Printf("- queryAllTuna:\n%s\n", buffer.String())
  return shim.Success(buffer.Bytes())

}
```

**MAIN FUNCTION**

```
func main()  {
        _error := shim.Start(new(SmartContract))
        if _error != nil {
          fmt.Printf("Error creating new Smart Contract: %s", _error)

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to go with the terminal in chaincode-docker-devmode?

```
cd fabric-samples/chaincode-docker-devmode
```

as in [Chaincode for Developers](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/chaincode4ade.html)
Me I got the same error when I forgot to jump in the repository
And make sure to put the version in CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME (e.g: CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0)